# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'com.example.materialdesignexample'

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-drawer

I am using eclipse and I have added support design navigation view like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.materialdesignexample.MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

but i am getting error like this

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute headerLayout in package com.example.materialdesignexample

please help me.....

Comment: at your parent layout you see this "xmlns" line can you plz show complete line what is written there

Comment: Thanks Shubhank for reply

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Comment: try to add one more line like this xmlns:yourApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass"

Comment: i have added line like this xmlns:com.example.materialdesignexample="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.materialdesignexample.MainActivity" but still i am getting same error

Comment: can you plz put the complete layout

Comment: Did you add dependency in `build.gradle`file?

Comment: i am using eclipse Piyush

Comment: @javed app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header" add this also

Comment: what you are using inside that drawer_header

Comment: in header layout i have just text view to show user name

Answer (score 0):

You have to import support-v7-appcompat library from android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat.

Create an android library project in eclipse for design support library and put the contents of directory android-sdks\extras\android\support\design in the design support library project
Link appcompat-v7 library to design support library project
Link support library project from your project.
You can not use directly the jar android-support-design.jar because you need some resources too (this is the reason of aar format).

Comment: i have done like this... but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

[image: editor code screenshot]

add compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'